# django google app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

Appengine has the handlers and Django the urls.py:

How can/should I match these two, to get the best result?

Can I/How can I pass all the requests that com to www.mysite.com to the urls.py?
What is best for the performance?

Comment: You really have a lot of poorly worded questions.  Did you try googling it? http://thomas.broxrost.com/2008/04/08/django-on-google-app-engine/

Comment: Thanks for the nice reply. I read that article. I am able to google. This article is excellent and I mentioned it in one of my other "poorly worded" questions. But it did not answer my question. It states that it is possible to use the handlers to pass to the urls.py. But it does not explain what other options you have and what my question would be: What the best solution is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone was wondering. This is what I was looking for:

> Tip: App Engine routes requests to Python scripts based on the URL and mappings specified in the application's app.yaml  file. A webapp WSGIApplication further maps specific URL paths to request handlers. How you use both mappings is up to you: You could have all non-static URLs go to a single Python script, and have the script dispatch all dynamic URLs to handlers. Or, you can group functionality into multiple WSGI applications run by different scripts, and use app.yaml to map the appropriate URLs to the appropriate applications.